# Download of a list of URLs

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, webclient

Let's say I have a list with about 300 Url's, like:

```
List<string> url;
```

I want to download the whole content from all Url's of the list. My solution is:

```
foreach (var k in url)
{
    WebClient Wc = new WebClient();
    Wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringKmlCompleted);
    Uri varUri = new Uri(k);
    Wc.OpenReadAsync(varUri);                
}
```

eventMethod:

```
void DownloadStringKmlCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{            
     StreamReader k = new StreamReader(e.Result);
     string temp = k.ReadToEnd();
     DoSomething(temp);  
}
```

My problem is: I get almost every time the same donwloaded string from the first url. I also tried to use the DownloadStringAsync method, but I had the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get almost every time the same downloaded string from the first url.

Are you saying that the value of `temp` in the `DownloadStringKmlCompleted` event handler is almost always the same, regardless of the url that you download from? That would be quite unexpected.

I would suggest that you use the `OpenReadAsync` overload that lets you pass a user token, and pass it the uri that you requested:

```
Wc.OpenReadAsync(varUri, varUri);
```

In your event handler, you can get that value from the `UserState` property in the event args:

```
Uri requestUri = (Uri)e.UserState;
```

You can then match up the request uri with the received data.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me. How are you populating your list of urls?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Demo d = new Demo();
            d.Process();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Demo
    {
        public void Process()
        {
            List<string> urls = new List<string>() { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.bing.com", "http://www.cnn.com", "http://www.engadget.com" };
            foreach (var url in urls)
            {
                WebClient Wc = new WebClient();
                Wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringKmlCompleted);
                Uri varUri = new Uri(url);
                Wc.OpenReadAsync(varUri, url);
            }
        }
        void DownloadStringKmlCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            StreamReader k = new StreamReader(e.Result);
            string temp = k.ReadToEnd();
            DoSomething(temp, e.UserState as string);
        }

         void DoSomething(string temp, string source)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('*', 100));
             Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}, Data: {1}", source, temp.Substring(0, 1000));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have some problems: 1) because Urls are called async, the order of called urls is not provided. Is it possible to sync them using async method? Reason: I am parsing a table. One of the elements of the line of the table is an url, where geocoordinates are stored. If the call order is not provided, I can't assign them to the desired array index..

Comment: @Pamp: See my answer. You can use the `OpenReadAsync` overload that lets you pass the url, which will be delivered in the arguments to the completed event.

Answer (score 0):

A truly wild guess here...you have a list of strings and you are using var in your foreach loop.  What happens if you change it to:

```
foreach (string k in url)
```

Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx)

for some detail on this.  It suggests var is optional in this case, but I'd be curious to try changing it and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: But if `url` is a `List<string>`, then type inference is going to turn that `var k` into `string k`. So your "solution" will have no effect.